# emacs macro doesn't define command

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, alias

I have written a macro that makes an alias and generates global keybinding based on the name.
I expect that if I add to my emacs config the following code for example:

```
(defkey-alias cool-function make-directory)
```

I will have command my-cool-function which creates a directory and a keybinding C-c c f to it. But after evaluation I have keybindings but have no command my-cool-function.

And if I do C-h k C-c c f I see:

```
C-c c f runs the command my-cool-function, which is an alias for `make-directory'.
```

I can not evaluate (my-cool-function) in *scratch* either.

But if I try to (macroexpand '(defkey-alias cool-function make-directory)) and then evaluate expanded s-expr it works.

What is the difference between calling macro and calling macroexpanding and then evaluation? And why alias is not callable?
Thank you.

Emacs version is GNU Emacs 24.2.1, Windows 7

The code:

```
;;; defining keys
(defun name-to-key(funname)
  " works like:
    'my-cool-function -> \"\C-cmcl\"  "
  (apply 'concat 
         "\C-c"
         (mapcar (lambda(str)(substring str 0 1))
                 (split-string (symbol-name funname)
                               "-"))))


(defmacro defkey-alias(alias function)
  "works like defalias but you should not quote symbols and sets global key mapping
Usage: (defkey-alias mkdir make-directory)"
  (let ((myalias (make-symbol (concat "my-" (symbol-name alias)))))
    `(progn
       (defalias ',myalias ',function)
       (global-set-key ,(name-to-key alias) ',myalias))))
```

UPDATED: Using (defun ...(interactive)(call-interactively 'function)) also does not work

Comment: Changing make-symbol to intern helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple: `(make-symbol (concat "my-" (symbol-name alias)))` returns a non-interned symbol.  I.e. it returns a symbol whose name is `my-cool-function` and yet it is a different symbol from the one you get when you write `(my-cool-function)`.  So instead of `make-symbol` you want to use `intern`.